# where clause with date range give strange result

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-ebs, xml-publisher

In an xml publisher report I have the following where clause:

```
    where  NVL(:P_ORDER_NUMBER, xx.order_number) = xx.order_number  
     and xx.ordered_date between NVL(TRUNC(fnd_date.canonical_to_date(:P_FROM_DATE)), xx.ORDERED_DATE) and NVL(TRUNC(fnd_date.canonical_to_date(:P_TO_DATE)), xx.ORDERED_DATE)  
    AND NVL(:P_CUSTOMER, xx.customer_id) = xx.customer_id
```

but its behavior is strange, with date range its result is ok, but with out date range its result is NULL.

I tried the following too:

```
where  NVL(:P_ORDER_NUMBER, xx.order_number) = xx.order_number  
 and ( NVL(TRUNC(fnd_date.canonical_to_date(:P_FROM_DATE)), xx.ORDERED_DATE) > xx.ordered_date  
       or  NVL(TRUNC(fnd_date.canonical_to_date(:P_TO_DATE)), xx.ORDERED_DATE) < xx.ordered_date )  
AND NVL(:P_CUSTOMER, xx.customer_id) = xx.customer_id
```

in concurrent program the dates parameters has FND_STANDARD_DATE.

Comment: and what is your question?

Comment: I want if user select only order_number it should display only that order, but if user select a date range and a customer, it must display orders by that customer with in that date range.

Comment: could you show some sample data and expected output, it would help us to understand what you want

Comment: add it to your question

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qv1ikEbAvNXfZIyXB6ZD_ystSEB3huo4_h7P6ULAbPg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Check this google sheet.

Comment: Please add your information to the question. Questions should be self-contained, without requiring visiting other websites. Thanks.

Comment: I think this is self-explained, need just a where clause where the user can select options and if no option is selected all the records should be displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are many ways of skinning this particular cat, this is just one method. By the way in your example you gave a date of 31st April, this does not exists.

```
SELECT TO_Char(ordered_date,'DD-MON-YYYY') as ordered_date,
    order_number, customer_name   
FROM order_tbl
WHERE NVL(:P_ORDER_NUMBER, order_number) = order_number
  AND ordered_date between NVL(TO_DATE(:P_FROM_DATE,'DD-MON-YYYY'),TO_DATE('01-MAR-1900','DD-MON-YYYY')) and NVL(to_date(:P_TO_DATE,'DD-MON-YYYY'),TO_DATE('31-DEC-2100','DD-MON-YYYY'))   
  AND NVL(:P_CUSTOMER_NAME, customer_name) = customer_name
```

Comment: in example, where is 31st April?

Comment: the problem is with YYYY, with YYYY it return nothing, and with 'RRRR' it works, can you tell me whats the difference?

Comment: 31st April is in your example 1 in the spreadsheet. I believe YYYY never assumes the century whereas RRRR does (so you can get away with not being explicit), i always use YYYY and have not problem as i specify the century so there may be other differences i am not aware of.